# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to create a new record and keep getting an error

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible

I have this piece of code..

```
// Contact
c.Name = IsItNull(contact.Name);
int newContactID = AddContact(c);
```

The AddContact method is

```
public int AddContact(Contact contact)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(AWJE.Database.SqlQuery<int>
            ("usp_InsertContact @Name", contact.Name));
    }
```

the storedproc is

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertContact]
    @ContactID int output,
    @Name nvarchar(50)
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

DECLARE @ERROR_SEVERITY int,
        @MESSAGE varchar(1000),
        @ERROR_NUMBER int,
        @ERROR_PROCEDURE nvarchar(200),
        @ERROR_LINE int,
        @ERROR_MESSAGE nvarchar(4000);

begin try
    insert into [Contact]
    (Name) values (@Name)
    set @ContactID = @@IDENTITY
end try

BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ERROR_SEVERITY = ISNULL(ERROR_SEVERITY(),'');
    SET @ERROR_NUMBER = ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),'');
    SET @ERROR_PROCEDURE = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),''); 
    SET @ERROR_LINE = ISNULL(ERROR_LINE(),'');
    SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'');

    -- Test if the transaction is uncommittable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. Rolling back transaction.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;

    -- Test if the transaction is active and valid.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is committable. Committing transaction.'
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
        END;

    SET @MESSAGE = 'Error Occured in Stored Procedure ' + cast(@ERROR_PROCEDURE as varchar(200)) + 
                    '; Line Number ' + cast(@ERROR_LINE as varchar) + 
                    '; Message: [' + cast(@ERROR_NUMBER as varchar) + '] - '
                    + cast(@ERROR_MESSAGE as varchar(255))

    RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, @ERROR_SEVERITY, 1);
END CATCH;

GO
```

The error gets thrown at

```
int newContactID = AddContact(c);
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? I have looked at other SO posts, that is somewhat similar to this error but they were about Linq and nothing like how I am doing it.
Any idea's?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue and the issue was in the AddContact method

```
public int AddContact(Contact contact)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(AWJE.Database.SqlQuery<int>
        ("usp_InsertContact @Name", contact.Name));
}
```

Instead of using SqlQuery, I used ExecuteSqlCommand in its place and that fixed the error. So now the method looks like this..

```
return AWJE.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
    ("usp_InsertContact @Name", contact.Name);
```